# Чтение бит в javaScript

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. Решил переписать один алгоритм с JS на C#, а так в JS не шарю, то столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами. Вот одна из них

`// before we start anything we need to get byte-aligned
  bstream.readBits( (8 - bstream.bitPtr) & 0x7 );`

Чисто интуитивно я понимаю, что тут происходит чтение бит из потока, но вот что в скобках происходит, не могу понять. Искал в инете функции bitPtr - не нашёл. Помогите разобраться. 
Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Вот сама функция, которую я переписываю.

```js
function RarReadTables(bstream) {
  const BitLength = new Array(rBC);
  const Table = new Array(rHUFF_TABLE_SIZE);

  // before we start anything we need to get byte-aligned
  bstream.readBits( (8 - bstream.bitPtr) & 0x7 );
  
  if (bstream.readBits(1)) {
    info("Error!  PPM not implemented yet");
    return;
  }
  
  if (!bstream.readBits(1)) { //discard old table
    for (let i = UnpOldTable.length; i--;) {
      UnpOldTable[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  // read in bit lengths
  for (let I = 0; I < rBC; ++I) {
    const Length = bstream.readBits(4);
    if (Length == 15) {
      let ZeroCount = bstream.readBits(4);
      if (ZeroCount == 0) {
        BitLength[I] = 15;
      }
      else {
        ZeroCount += 2;
        while (ZeroCount-- > 0 && I < rBC)
          BitLength[I++] = 0;
        --I;
      }
    }
    else {
      BitLength[I] = Length;
    }
  }
  
  // now all 20 bit lengths are obtained, we construct the Huffman Table:

  RarMakeDecodeTables(BitLength, 0, BD, rBC);
  
  const TableSize = rHUFF_TABLE_SIZE;
  for (let i = 0; i < TableSize;) {
    const num = RarDecodeNumber(bstream, BD);
    if (num < 16) {
      Table[i] = (num + UnpOldTable[i]) & 0xf;
      i++;
    } else if (num < 18) {
      let N = (num == 16) ? (bstream.readBits(3) + 3) : (bstream.readBits(7) + 11);

      while (N-- > 0 && i < TableSize) {
        Table[i] = Table[i - 1];
        i++;
      }
    } else {
      let N = (num == 18) ? (bstream.readBits(3) + 3) : (bstream.readBits(7) + 11);

      while (N-- > 0 && i < TableSize) {
        Table[i++] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
  RarMakeDecodeTables(Table, 0, LD, rNC);
  RarMakeDecodeTables(Table, rNC, DD, rDC);
  RarMakeDecodeTables(Table, rNC + rDC, LDD, rLDC);
  RarMakeDecodeTables(Table, rNC + rDC + rLDC, RD, rRC);  
  
  for (let i = UnpOldTable.length; i--;) {
    UnpOldTable[i] = Table[i];
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bitPtr` - это не функция а переменная, в которой хранится в каком конкретно бите вы сейчас находитесь...это порядковый номер бита. Переменная соответственно хранит значения от 0 до 7.

Читайте исходники библиотек, которыми Вы пользуетесь:
https://github.com/codedread/bitjs/blob/master/io/bitstream.js#L36

Comment: Весомое замечание, спасибо)

Comment: @Setplus, если нужна ещё помощь - приложите весь алгоритм к вопросу.

Comment: отредактировал вопрос, вставив функцию.